# Radiative cooling

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, convection

I have a hot object at a temperature of $200 \space C$. I am looking for a convective way to cool it down.

Would placing a cold copper (let us say $-10 \space C$) plate next to the hot object be sufficient to cool it down? How to calculate the distance between the plate and the hot object for optimum convection?

Comment: What do you mean by "sufficient"?

Comment: Your title and question don't match. No matter. Convection depends on lot of details, one of them being geometry of the setup. You need to give more details. If possible include a schematic drawing.

Comment: Convection means cooling by via movement of particles. A typical way to cool something via convection is by using e.g. a fan. Cooling something by placing it next to a cold metal plate is not a very effective way of cooling. There is no direct heat flow between the objects but rather the plate cools the air next to your object which in turn cools the object itself. Placing the plate in contact with the object (and perhaps also applying some thermal grease between the objects) would be more useful if your problem allows this.

Comment: You will have to specify the properties of the fluid (gas, liquid) between the two objects if you want an answer that pertains to convection. Please clarity if you just mean "radiation"?

Comment: I have air in between, I cannot use fans or make physical contact with the hot object.  Either convection or radiation? sufficient means to make at least 10 degrees C less hot. It is let us us a hot cup, and a copper plate. I want to know the optimum cooling distance between the cup and copper plate. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think radiative cooling would be the best way here. The radiation emitted by the object won't be powerful enough. By that I mean that the radiation emitted will have a low frequency. (From Wien's law)

Convection,on the other hand would require air molecules or fluid between the two objects. But even if the fluid were there, the molecules would just take up the heat and go upwards, and not towards the copper plate. Now that would piss us off, wouldn't it? But placing the copper plate above the hot object would work actually.

Comment: Generally radiative cooling will be placed in the roof if possible for that reason.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between convection and radiation heat transfer to me; I was not fully understanding them. Wouldn't it be possible to use radiation to cool down the hot object; or convection without using a fan or contact with the object?

Comment: I think you mean convective cooling JMac.

Comment: Cooling an object down by absorbing the radiation that it emits would take a lot of time, since objects emit pretty weak radiation at normal temperatures. Convection requires medium for heat flow, conduction requires contact between the two objects. To cool it down by convection, placing the copper plate above the other body should be the quickest way.

Comment: Thank you Dipesh Bhandari. But would not 'placing a copper plate above the hot object'  be conduction? Unless you mean no contact, and then may I know how to calculate the distance between them if the medium is air? and how long it will take to cool down? Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes I mean no contact. According to some basic books, the process of convective heat transfer is pretty complex since the fluid molecules go berserk once they absorb the heat from the body. But still some patterns regarding the heat transfer have been identified experimentally. Firstly, the rate of heat transfer is directly proportional to the area of the hot body exposed to the medium. But in this case it should depend upon the exposed area of the cooler body too. The rate of heat transfer depends upon the viscosity of the fluid.

Comment: Finally it has been verified that Heat current due to convection is approximately proportional to 5/4 th power of the temperature difference between the surface and the body of the fluid. Still, convection is pretty complex.

Comment: Thank you for the informative comments. I just figured out your comments today.

Comment: Dipesh Bhandari! I read recently that Aluminium can dissipate heat better than Copper. Does it mean it would be better cooling in the above case to cover the copper plate by an Aluminium plate? Thank you.